# Lost SSH access to ubuntu snappy core

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-core

I have ubuntu snappy core installed on my dragonboard.
I set it up using SSO.
It worked fine to ssh to the dragonboard from the desktop computer with ssh keys and no password.

Suddenly after years, when I ssh to snappy core it now prompts for a password that I don't have... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check that the Ubuntu Core system still resides at the same IP address. You might be seeing a different system on that network, and the IP addresses have shifted around.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is a good thought, however I checked and it is still under the same ip address. Is it possible the ssh key got changed somehow? Or can I connect a new SSO key?

Answer (score 0):

I have two answers to this question:

1. I found out that I was logging in with the wrong username.
   I was trying to login as the user who owned the ssh key, but I was supposed to login with the username of the core system. I forgot that somewhere along the line.
2. I discovered this because I wanted manually update the keys by mounting the snappy sd card on another system. Then editing /writable/user-data/username/.ssh/authorized_keys

(Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1646559)

This is where I rediscovered the username on the snappy core system was different from the username on my desktop.